# Documentation for ENMLWriter

Tags: python, evernote

I've got a script that outputs a .txt file. I'm looking to use the Evernote API (via the Python SDK) to create a new note in my Evernote account instead of just dumping a .txt file in my current working directory.

Is there a Python library that will take a txt file and convert it into ENML? I really don't care about fancy styling and would be okay with an ugly "plaintext" note.

I see some posts on the Evernote developer forums for something called "ENMLWriter". It's not clear if this is available as a Python library. I can't find any official documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're fine with a plaintext note, you can escape your plain text so that it's HTML-safe, then wrap it as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd">
<en-note>
<pre>plain text
goes here</pre>
</en-note>
```

The documentation for ENML is located here: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/enml.php

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll give this a shot but am still curious about the ENMLwriter. Is this an official Evernote library? Is it available in Python? See link below for an example of somebody who is using it.

Comment: This is the link where somebody is talking about ENMLwriter: https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/88653-adding-text-color-text-sizestyle-to-evernote-content-using-enml-writer/

Comment: @Trey ENMLWriter is a helper code which is a part of Evernote's iOS SDK: https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-ios/tree/master/evernote-sdk-ios/ENSDK/Advanced/Utilities/ENMLWriter and Windows (C#) SDK: https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-windows/tree/master/src/EvernoteSDK/Advanced/Utilities/ENMLWriter